# Problemas con json

Tags: javascript, php, json

Tengo datos que recojo de una base de datos local con `php`, cuando lo envio a mi fichero de `JavaScript` con `json.encode` me envía también la etiqueta de `style`. Sé que la conexión a la base de datos es correcta porque me trae los datos que he pedido, el problema es cuando lo convierto en `json` y los llevo a un fichero `JavaScript`.

Estoy usando un sistema en `CRUD`, en el que tengo un fichero `models` para la gestión y conexión a la base de datos, un fichero controlador para poder manejar toda la información, el fichero de vista y el fichero `JavaScript`.

Controlador:

```
 <?php
    class controler {
        private $data;

        public function __construct()
        {
            require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/models/conexion.php");

            $this->data = new conexion;
        }

        public function showData(){
          
            $datos =  $this->data->getData();
           
         return $datos;
        }
    }

    require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/models/montarTabla.php");

    $cc = new controler();
    
    $datos = $cc->showData();
 
    montarTabla::montar($datos);
    
    json_encode($datos);
?>
```

Fichero `JavaScript`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'controlers/controlador.php';
xhr.open('GET', url, true);

console.log(xhr);
xhr.onload = function(){


    if(xhr.status == 200){
        var json = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(json);
  
        // json = json.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,"");

        // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
        
    }else{
        console.log('error');
    }
}

xhr.send();
```

Resultado web:

[image: Este es el resultado, una sucesión de varios números]

Resultado de consola:

[image: Este es el resultado de la consola en el navegador]

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal o porque me surgen estos errores.

Comment: Por favor, los resultados de la consola agrégalos como texto y no como una imagen. Puedes hacer click en [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta codigo: agrega el codigo de la funcion  `montarTabla::montar()`

Pero puedes probar con  lo siguiente :

```
<?php
    class controler {
        private $data;

        public function __construct()
        {
            require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/models/conexion.php");

            $this->data = new conexion;
        }

        public function showData(){
          
            $datos =  $this->data->getData();
           
         return $datos;
        }
    }

    require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/models/montarTabla.php");

    $cc = new controler();
    
    $datos = $cc->showData();
 
    montarTabla::montar($datos);
    
    echo json_encode($datos);
    
    die();
?>
```